# regex failing to parse number from 0-23

Tags: javascript, regex

Why is this js regex failing to parse a number from 0-23?

```js
pattern = /([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3])/
"12".match(pattern) // => matches 12
"23".match(pattern) // => matches 2 (expected 23)
```

Comment: Should `00`, `01` etc match?

Comment: I'd think the clearest and easiest thing to do would be to check if the string is a representation of non-negative integer, and if it is, convert it to an integer and see if it falls in the range `0-23`. I'm curious why you chose to do it all with a regex, assuming it's not just an exercise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The regular expression returns the first match. The `[0-1]?[0-9]` matches `2`.

To get what you want, you need to adjust the order of patterns:

```
var pattern = /2[0-3]|[0-1]?[0-9]/;
```

---

```js
var pattern = /2[0-3]|[0-1]?[0-9]/;
document.write("12".match(pattern));
document.write('<br/>');
document.write("23".match(pattern));
```

**UPDATE**

Above will match `234` returning `23`. If you don't want to match it, you can use word boundary `\b`, or `^`, `$` anchors as Gergo Erdosi suggested:

```
var pattern = /\b2[0-3]\b|\b[0-1]?[0-9]\b/;

var pattern = /\b(2[0-3]|[0-1]?[0-9])\b/;
```

Comment: This will also match 234

Comment: @Christophe, Thank you for pointing that out. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is this js regex failing to parse a number from 0-23?

Because the first pattern in your regex will always tries to match the input string (ie, the pattern before `|`). If it found a match then it won't go for the next pattern (ie, pattern after `|`). Your first pattern matches `2`, so it fail to go for the next.

It would work if you reverse the order of the patterns.

**OR**

Better to use start and end anchors while validating the input string.

```
> var pattern = /^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3])$/g;
undefined
> "12".match(pattern)
[ '12' ]
> "23".match(pattern)
[ '23' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the regex matches the full string:

```
pattern = /^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3])$/
```

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close. Try something like this:

```
pattern = /^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3])$/
```

Your expression is currently matching the first part of the expression before it can evaluate the second half. There are a few ways to handle that, but matching the full length of your input is probably the easiest.

Comment: It wasn't when I started typing. :)